# Is it possible to verify username+password+mfa code?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement a simple Java GUI AWS client which will let IAM user do certain things. However, I want the user to supply valid username, *password* and MFA code. I could not find any related documentation in the Java SDK on how to do this. Any directions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck on this? This is a requirement of ours. Found http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html but have not tried it yet.

Comment: I am afraid, the AWS SDK does not give ability to use password authentication.